# How can you make two return's in a functional component?

Tags: reactjs

I have this component where I want to render some components with the `<Main />` Route but the login component shouldn't be with the `<Main />` route. I've thought of doing this by making two returns. One with the component and another one without.

```
import './App.css';
import './index.css'
import App from './App'
import Main from './main.js'
import {
  BrowserRouter as Router,
  Switch,
  Route,
  Link
} from "react-router-dom";
import Dashboard from './dashboard.js'
import Clients from './Clients.js'
import AddClient from './clientform.js'
import EditClient from './editclient.js'
import Landing from './landing.js'
import AddDiet from './addDiet.js'
import CalendarSection from './calendar.js'
import Login from './login.js'


export default function App() {
  return (
          <Router>
      <Switch>
        <Main /> 
        <Route exact path="/dashboard">
        <Dashboard />
        </Route>
        <Route exact path="/Clients">
        <Clients />
        </Route>
        <Route exact path="/addClient">
          <AddClient />
        </Route>
        <Route exact path="/Calendar">
          <CalendarSection />
        </Route>
        <Route exact path="/Clients/:id">
          <EditClient />
        </Route>
        <Route exact path="/Clients/:id/addDiet">
          <AddDiet />
        </Route>
      </Switch>
      </Router>
  )
}
  return (
    <Router>
    <Route exact path="/login">
        <Login />
      </Route>
    </Router>
  );
  }
```

Comment: There can be only one return. Only the first one will matter. On what basis(condition) are you gonna show one over the other?

Comment: then how can you show the `main` component in all th eother components except the `login` one?

Comment: Passing in a prop. Or have a state variable. Based on that write a condition inside your single return function

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like a classic case of needing a `isLoggedIn` bool state variable, then a check against that (ternary style or &&).

Comment: no, it is not that. It's about rendering a navigation in all the places except the login page

Answer (score 0):

You need to render based on authentication, if user logged in or not.
return (
isAuthenticated ? (your routes here) : (your login route)
)